# Text to work with responsive image and for text to stay in same position

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have tried every single trick in the book. I am working with Bootstrap 3.1 and this is what I am trying to do.

I have an image. The easy way is to add the text in photoshop and then to produce as an image but I definitely want to avoid for SEO purposes.

I am using the class="img-responsive" or "img-thumbnail" so that my images are responsive in nature. However, you can see that the biggest issue is that the text will not minimise or stay in the same position of where it is supposed to be.

Can anyone give me some guidance on how I should do this in CSS?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this js can help you.

http://simplefocus.com/flowtype/

Set the `font-size` in `em`.